# Better way to keep a list of items from a Http Request?

Tags: c#, .net, api, dependency-injection

I have a simple web api where each request "item" is stored in a list and thus a list is built without creating a new list per request. I have achieved this via dependency injection , but I want to know if there is a better way to do it?

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class MyController: ControllerBase
{
    private readonly List<string> _items;

    public WeatherForecastController(List<string> items)
    {
        _items = items;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetList([FromBody] CustomRequestObject request)
    {
        _items.Add(request.Item);

        return Ok(new CustomResponseObject(){Items = _items});
    }
}

public class CustomRequestObject
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
}

public class CustomResponseObject
{
    public IList<string> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSingleton<List<string>>(); //items stored after each request
    }

    //rest of startup methods left for simplicity
}
```

Comment: What is the expected lifetime of your data?

Comment: Are you not interested in retaining this data when the server reboots? How about after a period of not having received any web requests?

Comment: Why not simply use a DB?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends, how far you want to go with this.

Maybe the most common suggestion that I can give is that what you are doing is called Memory Caching. It's good to call things with a name that is widely understood.

Read this article about [In memory caching in Asp.net core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory).

Just to give you an example, what can be a possible issue with your code. Let's say you will have 2 instances of the same API, for scaling purposes. Guess what is going to happen? Every instance is going to work with its own in-memory list.

A side issue (not related to your question): you never except for function `GetList` to add something to the list. :)